# How can I copy a db mongo to another mongodb instance?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-shell

I want to copy my db called **users** binded by default to `localhost:27017` to another bind address. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You could try using this [copydb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/copydb/) command.
2. Otherwise, you could use mongo export, export the data to a file. Then import those data into the new database. [Back Up and Restore with MongoDB Tools](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/)

   Here is the doc of mongo export
   [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/)

Comment: I did not want to export and import, I thought there was a more direct way to do this. Thank you

Comment: I just remember this copydb command, hope it's helpful